# Radeon RX 570 poor work in Blender Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, drivers

My **RX 570 4GB** GPU is just enormous headache when in comes to rendering in Cycles. Most of the time my computer freezes and GPU driver crashes so I have to reset and wait for a looong 10 minutes reload (it always that long after freeze). Sometimes I even have to reinstall drivers.

Sometimes it freezes in the very beginning of render, sometimes in the middle.

And rarely it works perfectly and finishes render very fast.

And I don’t even want to talk about using RX570 in the viewport – it just doesn’t work.

This is just ridiculous because RX570 works perfectly with Radeon ProRender engine or LuxCore, I can play on medium-high settings in Cyberpunk 2077 and everything works fine.

**Cycles is the only problem for this GPU.**

I’ve tried almost all ever created drivers. All Adrenalins (and PRO drivers too), old and latest. Reinstalled them millions of times in millions different ways. It doesn’t depend on scene complexity, volume scatter or not – it fails to render most of the time on ANY render settings. I’ve tried all versions of Blender, I tried even E-cycles - nothing helps.

Can anyone help with this? Any hints? PLEASE. Maybe some other drivers for other hardware? This is just ridiculous because RX570 works perfectly with anything I do… except Cycles.

My computer:

Window 10 – latest x64 version,
Ryzen 5 1600 – 6-core 3.2-3.4 GHz,
16 GB RAM 2666 MHz,
Radeon RX570 4GB

Comment: How heavy is the scene that crashes? Is it as simple as the default cube? Or does it have millions of faces? I have a gpu of 4gb also, and it also doesn't work (The error that comes is: system is out of shared host and GPU Memory) if I have millions of faces in my scene. At that time I have to switch to CPU Compute to preview my scene.

Comment: Usually it doesn't depend on scene complexity, it fails to render any scene. But... I guess very complex scenes with volume scatter even worse. As I said, sometimes it works...

Comment: If you have these problems, I don't know any other solutions than just going to the preferences and enabling the gpu along with the cpu, or just switching to CPU Compute. Eevee might work since it doesn't use even close to the amount of gpu as cycles does.

Comment: I have no problems with CPU render other than it's very slow. I tried both CPU+GPU and GPU - it's always a problem when RX570 involved. So it doesn't really solve anything for me.

Comment: So if it is a very heavy scene, you will have to bear the slowness of the CPU or increase the amount of gpu memory in your computer. Try keeping your scene as simple as possible (Should not have millions of faces unless you have a very high grade CPU or GPU.)